# url rewrite if parameter NOT there already?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, rewrite

I've googled this but can't seem to figure out.

I'm looking to simply redirect any path requested to a GET parameter in index.php:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase  /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.+\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|ico)$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/site/index.php?request_url=http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

Now, redirect works but it's painfully slow, and gets executed twice.

Do I have to add another condition that checks whether request_url is already there? If so, how do I write that? Can't seem to figure out.

Right now it's not exactly a redirect loop, just really slow.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks a 1000!

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you change your rewrite rule to:

```
RewriteRule .* /site/index.php?request_url=http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

The main difference is to remove the leading `http://localhost` from the target.  That might help because if `%{HTTP_HOST}` is different from `localhost`, then Apache will issue an external redirect:  see the paragraph titled "Absolute URL" in the [RewriteRule documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).  That will take twice as long, as you say.

I also simplified the match pattern to just `.*`, but this is just a minor cleanup.  There's no need for the constraining matches `^...$`, and no need to capture with `(...)` either since you're not using the captured value in the rule target.